# Help with robots meta tag and X-Robots-Tag

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, meta-robots

I have two questions about robots meta tag and X-Robots-Tag:

- If a page has both `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header and `robots` meta tag, can this cause problems?

  For example:
  On HTTP response headers: `X-Robots-Tag: noindex`
  And on page source code: `<meta content='noindex' name='robots'/>`

  Which one is better? `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header or `robots` meta tag?
- On a frame redirect/masked page, does it count the inner robots tags?

  For example:
  `example1.com/masked-url` frame redirect to `example2.com/original-url`

  Does it count the meta tags of `example1.com/masked-url` or `example2.com/original-url`?

Comment: cf. this: "[Precedence of X-Robots-Tag header vs robots meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17930932/1429450)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a page has both `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header and `robots` meta tag, can this cause problems?

This should not cause "problems". Providing you make sure to provide the same values for both. eg. `noindex`, as in your example.

For search engines that support the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header, then this should always take priority. Where there is an equivalent HTTP response header for an in-page meta element, the HTTP header always wins.

> Which one is better? `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header or `robots` meta tag?

Well, you can't use the `robots` meta tag on non-HTML resources, such as PDFs and images etc. This is primarily why the `X-Robots-Tag` header was *invented*.

But whilst all the main search engines support the `X-Robots-Tag` header, it probably doesn't have as wide support as the `robots` meta tag, which has been around a lot longer.

> On a frame redirect/masked page, does it count the inner robots tags?

Yes. The document contained inside the frame is an entirely separate request and consequently, it's fetched just like any other single request.

> Does it count the meta tags of `example1.com/masked-url` or `example2.com/original-url`?

Both. They are two separate requests.